# bounce when facebook permissions already given in ios

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, facebook, ios5

I have an ios app integrated with facebook (for login and post in wall), so the problem is that when an recurrent user (logued with facebook - permissions given) do Log Out and try login again get:

```
" Already autorized "
" You have already autorized this app.
Press Okay to continue "
```

I want to avoid press the "Okay" button and facebook bounce to my app (like instagram, soundtracking and others).
So i need configure something in my facebook app?.

I added this code in my app but still not working:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url {
    return [[[FacebookManager sharedFb] facebook] handleOpenURL:url];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured out how to do that:

First:
Add this to your app

```
// Pre iOS 4.2 support
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url {
    return [facebook handleOpenURL:url]; 
}

// For iOS 4.2+ support
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url
    sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {
    return [facebook handleOpenURL:url]; 
}
```

Second: Complete the facebook app form (http://developers.facebook.com/apps/)
[image: Facebook app form]

Comment: Is not working with the new Facebook app, are you using the Facebook SDK 3.0?